# Find max in linked list by recursion

Tags: recursion

I want to find the max element in the linked list using recursion but my code doesn't work. I couldn't add the first element to the linked list to compare.

Here is my code:

```
void findmax(list L,int &m)
{
    if(L!=NULL)
    {   
        if(L->next!=NULL)
            if(L->Data<L->next->Data)
                m=(m>L->next->Data)?m:L->next->Data;
            else
                m=(m>L->Data)?m:L->Data;
        else m=L->Data;
        findmax(L->next,m);
    }
    else 
        return;
}
```

Comment: You should not _add_ anything to the list during search. BTW your solution looks like iterative solution, badly reshaped for recursion. You don't need any `m`.

Comment: tks for your help, I just got it recently

Answer (score -1):

algorithm :

```
1>  START //AFTER CREATING THE LINK LIST
2>  MAX= START->DATA
3>  TEMP=START //TEMPORARY NODE
4>  START=NODE
5>  THE CONTROL CHECKS WHETHER TEMP.DATA>MAX IF YES IT ASSIGNS TEMP.DATA TO MAX             6>  OTHERWISE GOTO STEP 7 TO ITERATE
7>  TEMP=TEMP.LINK //TRAVERSING THE LIST
8>  WHILE(TEMP.LINK!=NULL)
9>  TEMP=NULL
10> END
```

Comment: YOU CAN FOLLOW THIS TO GET YOUR ANSWER